# Recursively adding to a list

Tags: scheme, racket

The problem I have is that I have a list full of coordinates about a polygons corners called p1, p2, p3, p4. I need to recursively add them to a new list like this ((p1,p2) (p2,p3) (p3,p4) (p4,p1). And I have this list of them to start of (p1 p2 p3 p4). How do I recursively add them to a new list?

Comment: Have you tried? Include some code that doesn't work. (Maybe while doing that, you will actually make the code work :))

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in Racket, so take this solution with grain of salt. You can append the first value of list to end, and compute pairs by recursively.

```
 #lang racket

(define (pair-list l)
  (match l
    [(cons a (cons b '())) (cons (cons a b) '())]
    [(cons a (cons b t)) (cons (cons a b) (pair-list (cons b t)))]))

(define (compute-values l)
  (pair-list (append l (cons (first l) '()))))

(compute-values (list 1 2 3 4))
'((1 . 2) (2 . 3) (3 . 4) (4 . 1))
```